# mysqlclient.lib 8.0.21 makes memory leak

Tags: mysql, c

mysqlclient.lib 8.0.21 makes memory leak

if you run a query or connect it increase
I tested previous version and I compiled it from source code
but the result was same

visual studio 2019
mysqlclient.lib  version : 8.0.21

library download link :
https://cdn.mysql.com//Downloads/MySQL-8.0/mysql-8.0.21-winx64.zip

```
#include <iostream>

#include <mysql.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <process.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //first Snapshot
    printf("MySQL client version: %s\n", mysql_get_client_info());

    //start
    if (mysql_library_init(0, NULL, NULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not initialize MySQL client library\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    MYSQL* con = mysql_init(NULL);
    if (con == NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", "init faild");
        return 0;
    }

    mysql_close(con);

    mysql_library_end();
    printf("%s\n", "Finish Success");

    //Secod Snapshot
    getchar();
}
```

[image]

Comment: You have not asked a question. Perhaps you should share your results on https://bugs.mysql.com.

Comment: what version and how can i use this library in production ?

Comment: I don't think you've demonstrated a "leak".  If you had the body of your main() in a loop and each time through the loop it increased allocations and heap, that would be a leak.

Comment: in loop does not increase like first time
but how to release this heap